# Monitoring an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a requirement to have a users home workstation (mac) connect via ssh tunnel to a corporate bastion host (bastion.corpnetexternal.com) and through to a mac workstation (host.corpnetinternal.com) in the corporate network.  Here is the connection string:

`ssh -N -f -L 2345:host.corpnetinternal.com:22 user@bastion.corpnetexternal.com`

This is known to work, so no worries there.

The ssh tunnel needs to be automatically created and there must be monitoring ensure that it is functional end to end, and if not to be restarted.

Additionally, this functionality may not be dependent on or interrupted by a VPN tunnel that may or may not be present from the user remote workstation into the corporate network.

I would appreciate any suggestions.  Please, no comments on the why of using ssh tunneling if a VPN is available.  I have listed the requirements levied upon me.

Comment: A timeout is one case, inability (for whatever reason) to go end to end in the tunnel is another.  Restarting each minute is not an option since there is a process that takes place across the tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoSSH](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) does exactly what you need.

On MacOS, it can be installed through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with `brew install autossh`.

See the [README](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/README.txt) for usage instructions, or [here](https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/) and [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Autossh) for some examples.

Comment: My battery is about to die, so I have to link to examples instead of writing one here in the answer myself. I will try to come back later to finish.